# Data not returning from ajax POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I use this jQuery function to get data through Ajax:

```
function addContentPrt(cid){
   $.ajax({
    url: "<?=parseLink('addContent.php')?>",
    type: "POST",
    cache: true,
    dataType:'json',
    data: {id: cid},
    success: function(returnedData){
      console.log(returnedData);
    },
    error: function (xhr, tst, err) {
      console.log(err);
    } 
  });
}
```

and on the receiving end:

```
<?
  header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

  if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
  }

  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pharmacies WHERE id=$id");

  $r = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
  echo $r['title'];
  echo $id;
?>
```

the `echo $id` does return to ajax, but not `$r['title']`, with that it goes `null` in console. If I add some dummy text like `hello world`, I get a synthax error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token h {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token h"}`

What could be the cause of this and what could I do to fix it?

Comment: You're returning a string, not JSON.

Comment: Add a flag MYSQL_ASSOC at your mysql_fetch_array . Else you wont have array keys as title.. For testing better print_r($r); to check what you have at $r

Comment: you should look into json_encode.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you suggest a fix, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?
  header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

  if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
  }

  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pharmacies WHERE id=$id");

  $r = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
  echo json_encode('id' => $id, 'title' => $r['title']);
?>
```

and in your ajax success:

```
success: function(returnedData){
  console.log(JSON.parse(returnedData));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax, you specified the datatype as json which is the format expecting from the server, So in order to get a result, you need to return the json result from the server. Either by using json_encode($r) where $r can be any array.

Comment: I did that and it still returns `null`

Comment: ... or create the array yourself and pass it back:
`$results = ['id' => $id, 'title' => $r['title']];
 echo json_encode($results);`
Oh,  and you need to  provide the specific header. Check this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

Comment: Are you sure the $r['title'] or $id is setting in the server side?

Answer (score 0):

`return json_encode($r);` then you can read variable `$r` in sucess